# how to convert a sql having sub query in the from clause into Linq?

Tags: sql, linq

I have a sql statement as below, I want to translate it into Linq

```
select * 
from
(
select Top 12 *
from DailyData
where ddaCode = '600000' and ddaDate < '2008/12/31'
order by ddaDate desc) as X
order by ddaDate
```

How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

The From subquery becomes your first Linq query. Then this is queried in the second one.

```
var fromResults = DailyData.Where(x => x.ddaCode == "600000" 
                                       && x.ddaDate < new DateTime(2008,12,31)
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.ddaDate)
                           .Take(12);
var results = fromResults.OrderBy(x => x.ddaDate)
```

Comment: The result returns 12 earliest records. My query returns 12 records that just before the date of DateTime(2008,12,31) or in other words, the 12 records that most close to the date of DateTime(2008,12,31)